rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "file" : Input/output error (5)
Everytime I try to copy a file from one USB disk to another one (does not matter which one),I get this kind of error :
mario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/mnt/zroot-133/A_FILES/Backup/FreeBSD# rsync -avxHAXP FreeBSD-141-UFS-sdc-DarkMatter.img /mnt/sdj1/OS/Backup/BSD/FreeBSD --ignore-existing 

sending incremental file list
FreeBSD-141-UFS-sdc-DarkMatter.img

320,072,933,376 100%   83.57MB/s    1:00:52 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/mnt/zroot-133/A_FILES/Backup/FreeBSD/FreeBSD-141-UFS-sdc-DarkMatter.img": Input/output error (5)

WARNING: FreeBSD-141-UFS-sdc-DarkMatter.img failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).

FreeBSD-141-UFS-sdc-DarkMatter.img
320,072,933,376 100%   76.40MB/s    1:06:35 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/1)
rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/mnt/zroot-133/A_FILES/Backup/FreeBSD/FreeBSD-141-UFS-sdc-DarkMatter.img": Input/output error (5)

ERROR: FreeBSD-141-UFS-sdc-DarkMatter.img failed verification -- update discarded.

sent 640,302,152,539 bytes  received 60 bytes  83,716,042.70 bytes/sec
total size is 320,072,933,376  speedup is 0.50
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1334) [sender=3.2.4dev]

Can I know why ? and there is a parameter that I can use that fix that error ?
"--ignore-existing" is a parameter that I've got from here :
How to interpret and fix a Input/output error in Linux?
but it didn't work. From the post it's not sure how to fix the error.

As the accepted answer to the question you linked says, that indicates that rsync is having trouble reading that file. Did you try any of the recommended troubleshooting steps in that answer to figure out what's causing the error? if not... do that. Without knowing what's causing the error, it's impossible to say how to fix it.
